# Minimum distance of from a point to a curve

Tags: calculus

The minimum distance from the point (0,5/2) to the curve y=x⁴/8 is d.
What would be [d] where [.]  represents greatest integer fxn.

Comment: HInt: If $P : (t,t^4/8)$ is a point on the curve where the distance is minimized, then the normal line of the curve at $P$ will pass through $(0,5/2)$.

Comment: That gives a six degree polynomial t^6-20t²+16=0

Comment: @DaniyalMahmood The sextic polynomial in $t$ is a cubic polynomial in $t^2$ which has a integer root $t^2 = 4$, you can use this to factor the polynomial and get two possible real value of $|t|$. The root at $|t| = 2$ is the one you want (though you need to justify that).

Comment: Woah, I really couldn't see that, so thanks a lot